# firefox: Disable delay on download dialog buttons

Tags: firefox

How to minimize the delay between opening a download dialog and being able to hit the `ok` button?

It's useful if you know what you're doing (e.g. being web developer). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 53):

Go to `about:config` (type into address bar) and set `security.dialog_enable_delay` [setting](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Security.) to `0`.

Note: disabling this delay may in theory open you to some pretty non-standard security attacks described in [this article](http://www.squarefree.com/2004/07/01/race-conditions-in-security-dialogs/) (as [Otiel pointed out](https://superuser.com/questions/1023643/firefox-disable-delay-on-download-dialog-buttons/1023644#comment2182665_1023644)), but I wouldn't lose sleep about it.

Comment: Do you mean `security.dialog_enable_delay`? there is no `dialog_enable_delay` in my version of Firefox.

Comment: Note that there's a [reason for this delay](http://www.squarefree.com/2004/07/01/race-conditions-in-security-dialogs/) and that disabling it might lead to security attacks.

Comment: Yes, hence the `security` in name, but it seems those attack vectors are pretty arcane. If this question gains popularity to the degree that those attacks happen more often (doubtful), maybe it'll force Mozilla to handle this in a manner other than to annoy their users. Nevertheless, thanks for the article, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: The article makes a great point: *"Advanced users are the most susceptible to these attacks, because they type and double-click faster than they react to unexpected stimuli."* Rather than selecting `0`, it might be better to increase set the delay to a number higher than your default double-click speed.

Comment: Right, what pbarney said. ^ Just don't set it to 0. Instead of the default 1,000, maybe something more like the 200-600 range. Some of us operate at a frequency 2-3 times faster than others, and these delays are like hitting a stop light...