# Firefox save file dialog requires multiple enter key presses; How do I disable this "feature"?

Tags: firefox, download, save-as

Firefox has for a long time required multiple presses of the enter key to save a file.  I would like a single enter key press to always automatically act in a deterministic manner to actuate the save button.

I'm sure this change by Firefox is one of many that Mozilla has implemented to [protect users from themselves](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118077/is-the-save-button-delay-in-a-firefox-download-dialog-a-security-feature-what-d) ([Another thread explaining that same setting in Firefox](https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r20135590-FireFox-download-dialog-OK-button-greyed-out)).  Obviously, I don't think I need to be protected from myself so I want to find whatever setting in `about:config` is responsible for this and turn it off.

Sometimes when I am downloading a file, I want to rename it, so when I am done typing in the new filename, I like to hit enter.  Sometimes that enter clicks on the "save" button, sometimes I have to press enter up to 4 times.  Sometimes it doesn't matter how many times you press enter, it doesn't ever save the file.

Way back in the day, this was the default for all sorts of programs.  It used to be the default way Firefox behaved too.

I do have several extensions to Firefox, as well as [DirectFolders](http://www.codesector.com/directfolders), but I have encountered this problem before using most of those addons.

Comment: I'm encountering the same troubles. As explained in the answer below, we can disable the delay before the OK button becomes enabled. So this fixes part of the issue. However, in the dialog itself, I'm used to press Enter; most of the times it works, but sometimes it doesn't work. Quite irritating…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [firefox: Disable delay on download dialog buttons](https://superuser.com/questions/1023643/firefox-disable-delay-on-download-dialog-buttons)

Answer (score 1):

see if [Disable delay on download dialog buttons](https://superuser.com/questions/1023643/disable-delay-on-download-dialog-buttons) and setting the delay to 0 on the save button resolves the issue.

Comment: Setting the delay to zero opens a [http://www.squarefree.com/2004/07/01/race-conditions-in-security-dialogs/](potential attack vector) that targets power users. Rather than selecting `0`, it might be better to increase set the delay to a number higher than your default double-click speed, which you can make pretty fast, pretty much ameliorating the problem.